# Display a text message if the field is not found and not if found

Tags: php, wordpress, function, if-statement, plugins

I try to display a message like" Sorry no information here" if a field is not found and if field is found, no message appear. I use the ACF plugin for displaying field on front end in a user profil.

This is my code:

```
<?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id();             
 $label = 'user_' . $user_ID;
the_field('Information', $label);
?>
```

Anyone has an idea, I tried a lot of things but nothing helps

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add more appropriate tags to your questions. This will help you drawing more experts attention to your question. See also [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: ok thanks I'll add tags

Comment: what the field you want to check if empty or not ?

Comment: the field information